# Dirac measure with random variable as an input

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a paper that says: "...where $\delta_{X_t^j}$ denotes the Dirac measure at point $X_t^j.$" (for every $t$, $X_t^j$ is a random variable)

The Dirac measure I know is the following: We have a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on $X$. Let $x \in X$. Then for any $A \in \mathcal F, \delta_x(A) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $\delta_x(A) = 0$ if $x \notin A.$
Here $x$ is a point in the set $X$, but in the paper I have a random variable, so I am lost.

**My guess:** I know that for every $\omega \in \Omega, X_t^j(\omega) \in \mathbb R$ (where $\Omega$ is the probability space of the r.v. $X_t^j$, i.e. $X_t^j:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$). So I think I could interpret what the paper says in the following way: For every $A \subset \mathbb R$ and every $\omega \in \Omega$, $\delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A) = 1$ if ${X_t^j(\omega)} \in A$ and $\delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A) = 0$ if ${X_t^j(\omega)} \notin A$. Does this make sense? If not, what would it be the correct way to interpret the paper?

Edit: the sentence is in the eight line on the second page of the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.04175.pdf

Comment: Please post a link to the paper and specify at which page you find the claim

Comment: @Snoop: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my interpretation. What you find in the paper is a [random measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure) from $(\Omega,\mathscr{F}_t)$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$: indeed, for $A\in \mathcal{B}
(\mathbb{R})$, and $\omega \in \Omega$ fixed
$$A\mapsto \frac{1}{M}\sum_{j\leq M}\delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A),\quad \delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A)=\begin{cases}1&X_t^j(\omega)\in A\\
0& X_t^j(\omega)\notin A
\end{cases}$$
is a (at least additive) measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, while for $A\in \mathcal{B}
(\mathbb{R})$ fixed, and $\omega \in \Omega$
$$\omega\mapsto\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j\leq M}\delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A),\quad \delta_{X_t^j(\omega)}(A)=\begin{cases}1& \omega\in (X_t^j)^{-1}(A)\\
0& \omega \notin (X_t^j)^{-1}(A)
\end{cases}=\mathbf{1}_{(X_t^j)^{-1}(A)}(\omega)$$
is a $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable random variable, as $X_t^j$ are $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable thus $(X_t^j)^{-1}(A)$ are measurable sets.